# XSLT2.0: How to use nested for-each-group to compress xml records

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to use nested for-each-group and for-each with current-group() to compress like data into one xml record based on two keys. The first key being ID and second being Inv_Link

I am getting the expected results for the outer loop but the inner loop when I use //Record i get all keys in each result, with . i only get the first data element. Whats the proper selector to get all nested keys with in the parent key?

Thanks for any help!

XML Data Set

```
<Data>
    <Record>
        <ID>01_2019</ID>
        <Link>ICE2</Link>
        <Component_ID>DEBT</Component_ID>
        <Amt>1500</Amt>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>01_2019</ID>
        <Link>ICE1</Link>
        <Component_ID>EQT</Component_ID>
        <Amt>200</Amt>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>01_2019</ID>
        <Link>ICE1</Link>
        <Component_ID>CASH</Component_ID>
        <Amt>100</Amt>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>01_2020</ID>
        <Link>ICE3</Link>
        <Component_ID>CASH</Component_ID>
        <Amt>100</Amt>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

XSLT I'm using now:

```
   <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="ID">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <Record>
            <groupkey><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></groupkey>
            <AssetEvent>
                <ID> <xsl:copy> <xsl:value-of select="ID/text()" /> </xsl:copy> </ID>
                <DecompositionSequence>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="Link">
                    <groupkey><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></groupkey>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <Decompositions>
                            <Link> 
                              <ID><xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="Link/text()" /> </xsl:copy> <ID> 
                            </Link>
                            <DecompositionDataSequence>
                                <DecompositionData>
                                    <Component>
                                        <ID> <xsl:copy> <xsl:value-of select="Component_ID/text()" /> </xsl:copy> </ID> 
                                    </Component>
                                    <Amt> <xsl:copy> <xsl:value-of select="Amt/text()" /> </xsl:copy> </Amt>
                                </DecompositionData>
                            </DecompositionDataSequence>
                        </Decompositions>   
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
              </DecompositionSequence>
            </AssetEvent>
          </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Current Results, I get a total of 2 records but with none of the inner groupings (if i use //Record then i get all for both result records):

```
    <Record>
      <groupkey>ICE 01_2019</groupkey>
      <AssetEvent>
        <ID>ICE 01_2019</ID>
        <DecompositionSequence />
      </AssetEvent>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <groupkey>01_2020</groupkey>
      <AssetEvent>
        <ID>01_2020</ID>
        <DecompositionSequence />
      </AssetEvent>
    </Record>
```

What I'm expecting:

```
    <Record>
      <groupkey>01_2019</groupkey>
      <AssetEvent>
        <ID>01_2019</ID>
        <DecompositionSequence>
          <groupkey>ICE2</groupkey>
          <Decompositions>
            <InvestmentLink>ICE2</InvestmentLink>
            <DecompositionDataSequence>
              <DecompositionData>
                <Component>
                  <ID>DEBT</ID>
                </Component>
                <Amt>150</Amt>
              </DecompositionData>
            </DecompositionDataSequence>
          </Decompositions>
          <groupkey>ICE1</groupkey>
          <Decompositions>
            <InvestmentLink>ICE1</InvestmentLink>
            <DecompositionDataSequence>
              <DecompositionData>
                <Component>
                  <ID>EQT</ID>
                </Component>
                <Amt>150</Amt>
              </DecompositionData>
              <DecompositionData>
                <Component>
                  <ID>CASH</ID>
                </Component>
                <Amt>150</Amt>
              </DecompositionData>
            </DecompositionDataSequence>
          </Decompositions>
        </DecompositionSequence>
      </AssetEvent>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <groupkey>01_2020</groupkey>
      <AssetEvent>
        <ID>01_2020</ID>
        <DecompositionSequence>
          <groupkey>ICE3</groupkey>
          <Decompositions>
            <InvestmentLink>ICE3</InvestmentLink>
            <DecompositionDataSequence>
              <DecompositionData>
                <Component>
                  <ID>CASH</ID>
                </Component>
                <Amt>100</Amt>
              </DecompositionData>
            </DecompositionDataSequence>
          </Decompositions>
        </DecompositionSequence>
      </AssetEvent>
    </Record>
```

Comment: In general, if you want to group items to eliminate duplicates or to merge them then you don't use `for-each-group` with a directly nested `for-each` over the `current-group()` as that way you will map e.g. four input `Record`s with the same key to four output `Record`s. So usually within of an `<xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="...">` you use `<xsl:copy>...</xsl:copy>` to merge e.g. four input `Record`s with the same grouping key to one result `Record`.

Comment: And using paths starting with `//` inside any nested `for-each-group` or `for-each` also looks wrong as it searches the whole doc.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for that, helped clear up some of the issue. I've updated the post with where i'm stuck now. I'm having trouble getting all child keys. Guessing i'm using the wrong selector.

Comment: You might want to shorten the sample data to the relevant stuff for the nested grouping but then show a complete result sample respectively explain exactly how you want to group and map input to output. Doing `xsl:for-each-group select="."` seems pointless as a single item to be grouped by whatever key doesn't  achieve anything.

Comment: As I said, in general the approach is `<xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="some-key"><xsl:copy>...<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="some-other-key"><!-- sequence constructor for the inner group --></xsl:for-each-group></xsl:copy></xsl:for-each-group>`. From your question it is not clear which grouping keys you want (text says `Record/ID`, code has `concat(ID,'|',Description)`, output sample has a value `ICE 01_2019|1/1/2019|Jan Report 2019|4` which seems to contain yet some other data) nor which structure you want.

Comment: I've removed all unnecessary data element to make it easier to follow. Sorry i'm pretty new to xslt so it's been a bit of trial and error to figure this out.

Comment: The text now says you want to group by `Inv_Link` but in the edited sample only the first `Record` has such an `Inv_Link` child, the other `Record`s have `Link` children instead; I still fail to understand which input structure you have and how you want to group/map it to which result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input sample is

```
<Data>
    <Record>
        <ID>01_2019</ID>
        <Link>ICE2</Link>
        <Component_ID>DEBT</Component_ID>
        <Amt>1500</Amt>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>01_2019</ID>
        <Link>ICE1</Link>
        <Component_ID>EQT</Component_ID>
        <Amt>200</Amt>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>01_2019</ID>
        <Link>ICE1</Link>
        <Component_ID>CASH</Component_ID>
        <Amt>100</Amt>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ID>01_2020</ID>
        <Link>ICE3</Link>
        <Component_ID>CASH</Component_ID>
        <Amt>100</Amt>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

then the code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Record" group-by="ID">
        <xsl:copy>
            <groupkey>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            </groupkey>
            <AssetEvent>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ID"/>
                <DecompositionSequence>
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Link">
                      <groupkey>
                          <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                      </groupkey>
                      <Decompositions>
                          <InvestmentLink>
                              <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                          </InvestmentLink>
                          <DecompositionDataSequence>
                              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                          </DecompositionDataSequence>
                      </Decompositions>
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
                </DecompositionSequence>
            </AssetEvent>

        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <DecompositionData>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (ID, Link)"/>
        </DecompositionData>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Component_ID">
        <Component>
            <ID>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </ID>
        </Component>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Record>
   <groupkey>01_2019</groupkey>
   <AssetEvent>
      <ID>01_2019</ID>
      <DecompositionSequence>
         <groupkey>ICE2</groupkey>
         <Decompositions>
            <InvestmentLink>ICE2</InvestmentLink>
            <DecompositionDataSequence>
               <DecompositionData>
                  <Component>
                     <ID>DEBT</ID>
                  </Component>
                  <Amt>1500</Amt>
               </DecompositionData>
            </DecompositionDataSequence>
         </Decompositions>
         <groupkey>ICE1</groupkey>
         <Decompositions>
            <InvestmentLink>ICE1</InvestmentLink>
            <DecompositionDataSequence>
               <DecompositionData>
                  <Component>
                     <ID>EQT</ID>
                  </Component>
                  <Amt>200</Amt>
               </DecompositionData>
               <DecompositionData>
                  <Component>
                     <ID>CASH</ID>
                  </Component>
                  <Amt>100</Amt>
               </DecompositionData>
            </DecompositionDataSequence>
         </Decompositions>
      </DecompositionSequence>
   </AssetEvent>
</Record>
<Record>
   <groupkey>01_2020</groupkey>
   <AssetEvent>
      <ID>01_2020</ID>
      <DecompositionSequence>
         <groupkey>ICE3</groupkey>
         <Decompositions>
            <InvestmentLink>ICE3</InvestmentLink>
            <DecompositionDataSequence>
               <DecompositionData>
                  <Component>
                     <ID>CASH</ID>
                  </Component>
                  <Amt>100</Amt>
               </DecompositionData>
            </DecompositionDataSequence>
         </Decompositions>
      </DecompositionSequence>
   </AssetEvent>
</Record>
```

That uses the XSLT 3 declaration `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` but if you use an XSLT 2 processor you can replace it with the identity transformation template.

Comment: Thanks this helped out  lot, sorry for the original mess i posted.